# Android phone cannot press any buttons after boot

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, unbricking

My Samsung Galaxy S 4G seems to be bricked. I must have done something horribly wrong to get it to be in this state. Sometimes, it hangs on the Samsung screen when booting up. Other times, it is unresponsive after the first five seconds. I think it's the media scanning that's causing this, but I am not sure. Samsung Kies and ADB both do not detect the device. I did a factory reset when this was happening, and it seems to have made it worse. Is my phone un-savingly bricked? How can I fix it?

When the phone was still working, I think I deleted some system files accidentally. 
This could be why it's not working properly.

Edit: Now it seems like I can't even get pass the Samsung Screen.

Comment: As you assume the media scanner being involved: have you tried to boot without the external SDCard inserted? It might well be a corruption there causing that (and the media scanner might trigger this when scanning the card).

Comment: Water damage, ugly fall, electricity surge! These are some of the issues that may lead your device to halt on boot! (Assuming that you haven't been doing some root/ROM changes) Can you clarify if any of this situations happened recently?

Comment: @Izzy Media scanner still shows up when I remove sdcard.

Comment: @Zuul I have been screwing with the ROM and root...

Comment: @jeffreylin_ Please include details on your "screwing" with your question: what exactly did you do? This might give details helping us to help you. As for the media scanner: sure it runs without the card as well; but a "broken card" can no longer cause it to freeze if not inserted ;)

Comment: Have you tried flashing a new ROM using Odin or Heimdall? Erasing data in the process, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Heimdall One Click Collection](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1358498), I was able to restore my device back to the Stock ROM.

In Windows, it requires the [Visual Studio C++ Runtime](https://www.google.com/search?q=visual+studio+c%2B%2B+runtime+libraries). After putting the phone in Download Mode, all you need to do is to press the flash button.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have damage some critical files that are preventing your device from booting properly, with this in mind, you can try:

## One-Click UnBrick

<sup>Credits go to [AdamOutler at XDA-Developers Forum.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=15330252)</sup>

[image: One-Click UnBrick screenshot]

> ### About One-Click UnBrick
>
> - Will work on all Samsung devices which use Odin3
> - Is a single, portable executable
> - Is the first one-click anything for our devices on Linux
> - Works on Mac
> - Works on Windows
> - Is open source
> - Is programmed in Java
> - Deploys and installs Heimdall for your OS
> - Is super easy to use.... Only one button!

---

## Instructions

1. Copy [OneClick.jar](http://click.xda-developers.com/api/click?format=go&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&loc=http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=15330252&v=1&libId=68d69cd1-c2b2-498c-8662-65edd949590d&out=http://heimdall-one-click.googlecode.com/files/OneClick.jar&ref=https://www.google.pt/&title=%5BRELEASE%5D%20One-Click%20UnBrick%20updated%2010july11%20-%20xda-developers&txt=Click%20Here%20to%20Download%20One-Click%20UnBrick%2010July11%20from%20GoogleCode&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_137479859533914) to your Desktop or any other folder on your computer.
   It won't work on a network share.
2. Double click the file to run it.
   As long as you have [Java installed](http://click.xda-developers.com/api/click?format=go&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&loc=http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=15330252&v=1&libId=68d69cd1-c2b2-498c-8662-65edd949590d&out=http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre&try=1&ref=https://www.google.pt/&title=%5BRELEASE%5D%20One-Click%20UnBrick%20updated%2010july11%20-%20xda-developers&txt=Do%20you%20have%20java?&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_137479867597617) on your machine you are up and running.

   **Linux users:**
   Mark this file as executable:

   ```
   chmod +x OneClick.jar
   ```

   **All platforms:**
   Double Click to run, OR, right click and open with Java, OR from command line:

   ```
   java -jar OneClick.jar
   ```

   **Windows users:**
   For some versions of Windows as a work around to UAC (User Access Control, the annoying popups), a executable called "OneClickLoader.exe" has been deployed to the same folder as OneClick.jar. It is important that you do not rename OneClick.jar until after running OneClickLoader.exe
3. right click OneClickLoader.exe and select "Run as Administrator"
   Setup should be run-of-the-mill.

---

## Attention:

Have you tried to go back to Download Mode?

> If it's still able to go back into Download Mode, you don't need this software.
> Just turn your Captivate into the Download Mode and flash back to STOCK Eclair or Froyo using Odin 1 Click or whatever similar.

---

## Links:

- Click [Here](http://click.xda-developers.com/api/click?format=go&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&loc=http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=15330252&v=1&libId=68d69cd1-c2b2-498c-8662-65edd949590d&out=http://heimdall-one-click.googlecode.com/files/OneClick.jar&ref=https://www.google.pt/&title=%5BRELEASE%5D%20One-Click%20UnBrick%20updated%2010july11%20-%20xda-developers&txt=Click%20Here%20to%20Download%20One-Click%20UnBrick%2010July11%20from%20GoogleCode&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_137479859533914) to Download One-Click UnBrick 10July11 from GoogleCode
- You will need Java installed on your computer: [Do you have java?](http://click.xda-developers.com/api/click?format=go&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&loc=http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=15330252&v=1&libId=68d69cd1-c2b2-498c-8662-65edd949590d&out=http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre&try=1&ref=https://www.google.pt/&title=%5BRELEASE%5D%20One-Click%20UnBrick%20updated%2010july11%20-%20xda-developers&txt=Do%20you%20have%20java?&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_137479857419912)

Comment: Ok, I can access download mode, but Odin doesn't seem to think I'm in it.

Comment: The OneClickUnbricker doesn't work because like Odin, it doesn't recognize my phone.